# Why does the BackgroundWorker's ProgressChanged event work without calling RunWorkerAsync?

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a question regarding the `BackgroundWorker`. I can call the `ProgressChanged` event without having started the thread with `RunWorkerAsync`.

I don't understand why this works. How can it notify the original thread if the new thread didn't even start yet?

This seems to work regardless, since it updates the GUI without a problem, which wasn't like this before I implemented the `BackgroundWorker`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling `ReportProgressChanged()` will always raise the `ProgressChanged` event regardless of which thread it was called from.

Inside the inplementation of `ReportProgressChanged()` is a mechanism which raises the event on the UI thread if it wasn't called from the UI thread. If `ReportProgressChanged()` *is* being called from the UI thread, then it just raises the event without needing to do that extra marshalling.

Comment: More information on how events work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx . It is good to know how to use events in C#. They can be very handy in many situations to get a more logical flow in your program.